# How to handle NULL object property with FirstOrDefault using Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

My real application issue looks exactly like below

```
Employee empl = new Employee(397947, "David", "Redson", 80000);
        employees.Add(empl);
        employees.Add(new Employee(174966, "Alfred", "Swanson", 50000));
        employees.Add(new Employee(848024, "Alima", "Bieyrou", 40000));
        employees.Add(new Employee(number: 397462, fName: "Robert",
                                     lName: "Nants", salary: 30000));


string s = employees.Where(a => a.EmployeeNumber == 20000).FirstOrDefault().FirstName;
```

As I am using `FirstOrDefault`, it is throwing error when there is no matching record. If there is a matching record, I want to return the value, or else it can be null or empty..

Comment: Why not just check if return value is not null before accessing the FirstName property?

Comment: Are you wanting SingleOrDefault().

Comment: Ii think `FirstOrDefault` is best option see answer of @hariprasad

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You need not use `Where` and the `FirstOrDefault` in this case, you can specify the filter condition inside the `FirstOrDefault` itself. But which will give you null if there are no records satisfying the condition(because in the absence of the first value it will give you the default value, for reference type objects the default value is `null`), you should check for `null` before accessing the value, which will throws [`NullReferenceException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). So Use like this:

```
var Employee=employees.FirstOrDefault(a => a.EmployeeNumber == 20000);
if(Employee!=null)
{
  string employee_name=Employee.FirstName;
  // code here
}
```

Or else you can use `?.` to check for `null` like this:

```
string employee_name = employees.FirstOrDefault(a => a.EmployeeNumber == 20000)?.FirstName;
```

Comment: This method is not efficient. FirstOrDefault retrieves the complete Employee to local after which you throw away most fields. Use your SQL server profiler to check the SQL statement.

Comment: The null-propagating operator `?.` (aka Elvis operator) is not allowed in a queryable (LINQ-to-SQL or LINQ-to-Entities) collection. However, it works fine for a LINQ-to-Objects collection.

Answer (score 63):

Select the string in your linq statement before your FirstOrDefault and you get your string or the default string:

```
string s = employees.Where(a => a.EmployeeNumber == 2000)
                    .Select(a => a.FirstName)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

This has the advantage that only the value that you will be using will be fetched, not the complete Employee.

Comment: Hmm, I'm wondering why this most natural solution is totally ignored. +1

Comment: Putting the FirstOrDefault at the end will often mean that the entire result is loaded into memory before the first element is selected.   Replacing the Where with the FirstOrDefault will cause the underlying query to implement the selection as a Top 1.   This boils down to differences in the implementation of the underlying LINQ provider.

Comment: I don't agree. FirstOrDefault does not load the entire collection. According to the reference source. It gets the enumerator, does ONE MoveNext and returns the Current. See https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs

Comment: For IQueryable it depends on the class that holds `Queryable.Expression`. Entity Framework DbSet class makes it a SQL "Select Top 1 ..." So also for IQueryable I don't see any evidence that the complete collection is downloaded.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, more clear, shorter, and less data transferred in the majority case.

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse Amazing.

Answer (score 10):

May be you can try using null propagation to make it easier:

```
string s = employees.Where(a => a.EmployeeNumber == 20000).FirstOrDefault()?.FirstName;
```

Comment: worth to mention that the null propagation operator only works in C# 6+

Comment: @fubo C#6 is the **current** version of C#, I don't see why we need to mention that. We don't do that for other C# versions.

Comment: As I commented earlier, this is not allowed in a queryable (LINQ-to-SQL or LINQ-to-Entities) collection because the operator is not translated.
@Ivan Stoev We do mention C# versions in other answers where a behavior is not implemented in earlier versions. It's usually mentioned where only some versions support the operation being discussed.

Answer (score 9):

In `C# 8` and later use the `null-coalescing` operator `??` and null checking operator `?`.

Like this:

```
string s = employees?.Where(a => a.EmployeeNumber == 20000)
                     .FirstOrDefault()?
                     .FirstName ?? string.Empty;
```

To avoid any null exceptions in the `employees` list and any employee properties.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`DefaultIfEmpty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419(v=vs.100).aspx). Consider the following example:

```
var entries = new Employee[0];
var result = entries.DefaultIfEmpty(new Employee() { FirstName = "<default name>" }).First().FirstName;
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the easiest way is just to write the next line:

```
string firstName = employees?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.EmployeeNumber == 20000)?.FirstName ?? null;
```

What the code does is: if `employees` isn't `null`, and if it found an object in the list of `employees` where `EmployeeNumber` equals 20000, and if this instance isn't null, you'll get the `FisrtName` property, otherwise the string `firstName` will be null.

Answer (score 3):

If you are sure you've only one record for a given `EmployeeNumber`  you could use `SingleOrDefault` extension.

```
var item = employees.SingleOrDefault(a => a.EmployeeNumber == 20000);
string s = "";

if(item!= null)
{
    s = item.FirstName;
    // your logic ... 
}
```

In case if you have multiple records for given employeenumber, use `FirstOrDefault` but do null check before accessing properties.

```
var item = employees.FirstOrDefault(a => a.EmployeeNumber == 20000);

string s = "";    
if(item!= null)
{
    s = item.FirstName;
    // your logic ... 
}
```

Comment: And how is he supposed to use variable s outside your if block?

Comment: there is a chance for multiple records, can  use in the below way    if (employees.Where(a => a.EmployeeNumber == 397947).FirstOrDefault() != null)
            {
                string s = employees.Where(a => a.EmployeeNumber == 397947).FirstOrDefault().FirstName;
            }

Comment: In that case use the second approach.

Comment: @fubo Updated it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can do like below

```
var employee = employees.FirstOrDefault(a => a.EmployeeNumber == 20000);
return employee != null ? employee.Name : string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign value after checking if the object is null.

```
var emp = employees.Where(a => a.EmployeeNumber == 20000).FirstOrDefault();

string s = emp == null ? string.Empty: emp.FirstName;
```

Comment: What is the need for `Where`, you can specify the condition inside the `FirstOrDefault`

Comment: instead of var can  use like the below   if (employees.Where(a => a.EmployeeNumber == 397947).FirstOrDefault() != null)
            {
                string s = employees.Where(a => a.EmployeeNumber == 397947).FirstOrDefault().FirstName;
            }

Comment: @python : why would you execute the same expression two times just for checking null condition? It's better to store the result in a variable and then check the value of the variable. DRY principle- Don't Repeat Yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
string employee_name = employees.FirstOrDefault(a => a.EmployeeNumber == 20000)??new Employee();
```

We can use this and avoid null exceptions occurring when and object is not created.

Answer (score -1):

A note for EFCore6+/EF7+, the [Queryable.FirstOrDefault Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.firstordefault?view=net-6.0) returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value.

NULL is no longer returned. To check for no value found:

```
  int e = integerReturningQuery.FirstOrDefault();
  if (e == default) //default for int is 0
```