# Test Null after FirstOrDefault

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have the following Linq expression in EntityFrameworkCore:

```
var models = await products.Select(product => new ProductModel {
  Id = product.Id,
  ProductType = new ProductTypeModel {
    Id = product.ProductType.Id,
    Name = product.ProductType
             .ProductTypesI18N
             .FirstOrDefault(y => y.LanguageCode == languageCode)?.Name
  }
}.ToListAsync()
```

I get the following error:

```
An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator.
```

It there a short way to not fire an error if FirstOrDefault returns null?

**Note:**
I think that might be a better way instead of using FirstOrDefault.
For example, in the following code line: `new ProductTypeModel {`

Comment: Try encapsulating your entire expression in parenthesis or into it's own "var" variable then adding the ?.Name. Or you could use null colacing
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle NULL object property with FirstOrDefault using Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38495629/how-to-handle-null-object-property-with-firstordefault-using-linq)

Comment: @ZakkDiaz null cloaking won't work, I think, because I will need to return name ...

Comment: That's odd because your null propagating operator is not part of an expression tree lambda as far as I can tell.  How exactly is that query being used?  Is it inside of a larger query?

Comment: @juharr Yes, it is part of a larger query. I updated my code. And thinking better I think I should not use FirstOrDefault because it loads the entire entity to memory? Maybe doing something before?

Comment: I found similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44681362/an-expression-tree-lambda-may-not-contain-a-null-propagating-operator

Comment: If `products` is an `IQueryable` from a DbSet you don't need to check for `null` because the query is executed as SQL which doesn't have a null reference concept.

Comment: @MiguelMoura Has your this problem solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the Name of the ProductType that you want before your FirstOrDefault:

```
Name = product.ProductType.ProductTypesI18N
         .Where(productType => productType.LanguageCode == languageCode)
         .Select(productType => productType.Name)
         .FirstOrDefault(),
```

Simple comme bonjour!